# Designing database for Multilanguage dictionary

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary

I want to make a database for English to Myanmar multi-ethnics dictionary.

Currently,I have 4 English to Myanmar Ethnic dictionary data for English to Myanmar/Burma Languages.

Example:

English#WordTyp#Transalation#Eg_Sentences#Synonyms

Love #(n)# translation # Language 1 #Eg_Sentences#Synonyms

Love #(v)# translation # Language 2 #Eg_Sentences#Synonyms

Love #(v)# translation # Language 3 #Eg_Sentences#Synonyms

Love #(n)# translation # Language 4 #Eg_Sentences#Synonyms

"WordType" can be "verb", "noun" , "adverb", etc...

Here is example data entries

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjMW.png

I am not good in Database design, I am thinking about to create "6" tables:

- English_Word
- PartOfSpeech
- Translation
- Language
- Synonyms
- Example_Sentences

in near future, I want to add more Myanmar/Burma ethnic languages.

One English word can have many word type(noun,verb,adverb,..) and can be translated(just a strings) into many languages.

But how is the relations between them? Here is my first database schema.

Could you give me feedback on my draft database table design?
[my draft database table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjj2h.png)

Many thanks in advance.
regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id Should be a auto increment field and we can treat all words (in all languages as words )

```
  WORD (ID,NAME,LANGUAGE_ID,TYPE_ID) //TYPE_ID AND LANG_ID ARE FOREIGN KEYS
TYPE (ID,NAME) // PART OF SPEACH
LANGUAGE (ID,NAME)
SENTENSE (ID, EXAMPLE)
SYNONUMS (ID,WORD_ID,SYNONYM_ID) //TYPE_ID AND SYNONYM_ID ARE FOREIGN KEYS TO WORD TABLE (SYNONYM IS ALSO A WORD)
DICTIONARY (WORD_ID,TRANSLATION_ID, SENTENSE_ID) // TRANSLATION IS ALSO A WORD


LANGUAGE 

id     name
1      english
2      tamil
3      gggggg

TYPE
ID    NAME
1     NOUN
2     MMMMM

WORD
ID  NAME LANGUAGE_ID TYPE_ID
1   LOVE    1          1
2   $#%#$%  2          1
3   PASSION 1          1
4   HHJHJHJ 1          2

SENTENCE 
ID   EXAMPLE
1 HAFKAKJDHAKJFHAHLFALFLASLDAL

SYNONUMS

ID   WORD_ID     SYNONYM_ID
1      1             3       //LOVE =>SYNONUMS PASSION
2      1             4

DICTIONARY
WORD_ID   TRANSLATION_ID   SENTENSE_ID
1              2               1         //LOVE $#%#$% HAFKAKJDHAKJFHAHLFALFLASLDAL
```

Comment: this is high level design and let me know your concerns then i can help you on modifying it and how to address those things

Comment: Thanks, Mahesh, your design help me a lots. Sorry for my late reply. 
DICTIONARY (WORD_ID,TRANSLATION_ID, SENTENSE_ID) // TRANSLATION IS ALSO A WORD - In this Dictionary table WORD_ID & SENTENSE_ID are ForeignKey and TRANSLATION_ID is also ForeignKey isnt'?

Comment: @zogam yes you correct you can identify foregin keys easyly on all tables because they will come with thier "tablename_id " pattern (except translation_id)

Comment: @zogam please mark this as answer if it work for you

Comment: Why do I need language_Id in Word? If I want to only English->Myanmar, do we need to have language_id for Word table?

Comment: I am a little bit confuse with the schema. What would look like if I only transalate "English" to "Myanmar languages". I don't need to save "Myanmar words" in "Word" table.

Comment: There will be only English to Myanmar languages transalations.

Comment: But you also need examples for every language, so this sentence table should have a language fk. And synonym is spelled with a 'y'